# Multithreading TCP client

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, sockets, tcp

Ok some background. I am writing a TCP client which gets information from minecraft servers.

i want to make a client which gets info from 10 servers simultaneously. So for this i have to use multithreading.

here is the code i have so far, but it doesnt seem to work.

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Module main
Private socketclient As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()

Sub Main()
    Dim serverList() As String = _
    {"ag1.playeoe.com", "lava-craft.net", "play.diamcraft.com", "mc.ecocitycraft.com", "main.kingscrafters.com", "pvp.cursecraft.net"}

    For i = 0 To serverList.Length - 1 Step 1
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to " & serverList(i) & ":" & port & "..")
        socketclient.BeginConnect(serverList(i), "25565", New AsyncCallback(AddressOf connect), socketclient)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

Public Sub connect(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    If socketclient.Connected = True Then
        Console.WriteLine("Connected!")
        Dim stream As NetworkStream = socketclient.GetStream
        Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = {&HFE}
        Console.WriteLine("Sending Data...")
        stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

        'copied
        Console.WriteLine("Recieving Response..." & vbNewLine)
        Dim bytes(421) As Byte
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(421))

        'Trim Bytes
        Dim trimbytes(bytes.Length - 3) As Byte
        Array.Copy(bytes, 3, trimbytes, 0, bytes.Length - 3)

        'Process output
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        For i As Integer = 1 To 241 Step 2
            If trimbytes(i) <> 0 Then
                sb.Append(ChrW(BitConverter.ToInt16(trimbytes, i)))
            End If
        Next i
        Dim message() As String = sb.ToString.Split("§")

        'Display OutPut
        Console.WriteLine("----------Response Begin----------")
        Console.WriteLine(message(0))
        Console.WriteLine(message(1))
        Console.WriteLine(message(2))
        Console.WriteLine("----------Response End----------" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)

        socketclient.Close()
    End If
End Sub
End Module
```

now this doesn't seem to work. I get only data from the first server but not the rest. When i debug it, it shows that the socket is not open for the other servers.

here is the output 
[image: OutPut of the program]

Comment: Err..  I don't know any VB and only opened this by mistake, but you need a separate socket instance for each server connection - you can't just use the same one each time.

Comment: Other than the call to sleep, I don't see any multithreading in this code at all. Also make your client socket new in the top of your loop instead of at the top of the program.

Comment: @grieve - that's what I thought.  Re. multithreading, is the connect-handler not called in the context of some threadpool thread, (I don't know 'cos I know no VB:)?

Comment: @grieve If i add it to the top of the loop, how will i access it in the "connect" sub

Comment: @VidhuShresthBhatnagar: Pass it in as a parameter to the function.

Comment: @MartinJames: You're right the call back to connect will be on its own thread. Not sure if it is backed by a thread pool or not (probably).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a VB expert by any means so you will need to play with the syntax, but this should get you started:

```
Module main

Sub Main()
    Dim serverList() As String = _
    {"ag1.playeoe.com", "lava-craft.net", "play.diamcraft.com", "mc.ecocitycraft.com", "main.kingscrafters.com", "pvp.cursecraft.net"}

    For i = 0 To serverList.Length - 1 Step 1
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to " & serverList(i) & ":" & port & "..")
        Dim socketclient As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
        socketclient.BeginConnect(serverList(i), "25565", New AsyncCallback(AddressOf     connect), socketclient)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

Public Sub connect(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim socketClient As CType(ar.AsyncState, System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient)
    If socketclient.Connected = True Then
    ... // Everything else can stay the same.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already passing the client to the BeginConnect as the state variable.  You can access the specific client via the IAsyncResult (ar) that is passed to your callback. Just cast the state property into a TcpClient.

---

Sorry, this assumes you took the advice of the commenters and new ed a new client object for each server address.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing parameter PORT of beginConnect function as string, not an integer.

The implicit convertion pass 0 as parameter in the function call.

(int) "25565" = 0